# Error Loading Topicmodels package in RStudio

Tags: r, topicmodels

I keep getting this error when loading topicmodels:

```
>Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘topicmodels’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘tm’
```

I already installed the package, so I don't know why this keeps happening, any ideas?

I reinstalled the package and also updated R and Rstudio, but nothing is changing

Comment: What happens when you try to install the `tm` package?